# Whats wrong with my facebook like button (fb plugin)

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

Now and again when the page refreshes (about 1 in 3) my facebook like button goes all weird and glitchy as seen in this image...

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code i am using to show the button (with PAGE_URL as actual URL):

```
<fb:like send='false' layout='standard' href='PAGE_URL' 
    width='500' show_faces='false' font='tahoma'></fb:like>
```

All the javascript SDK is correct and the like button works, it just does that weird thing shown in the image.
Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the image resource isn't loading.  Why don't you take a look at the source when you observe the error and confirm that the image should be displayed.  If it's simply not loading, that'd be a Facebook issue, and you should log a ticket.

Comment: Look at the source and confirm the image should be displayed? The source just says what the above code says, error or not, there is no image code??

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to compare the source code of the element (inspect it with Firebug or something) when it works against when it does not work.  If they match, then the problem lies with Facebook.